# Test automation

Tags: testing

Hey I'm looking at implementing some test automation running on target devices and reporting back up to Azure. Has anyone implemented any sort of test automation where metrics and pass/fail information reported to a central server?  For example, if I run a blink app on a Rasp Pi 3, I would like to monitor the state of all the pins and when they change, along with the physical changes (LED flashing on/off) and report when it changed and if it passed failed.  Are there any tools, libraries, samples/examples of how to implement this?